# What does import/resolver do in .eslintrc.js file?

Tags: typescript, eslint, yarnpkg

I have implemented yarn berry in my project instead of using node_modules.

After I migrate yarn berry (yarn-3.1.1 version), the eslint error below started to occur in a file, at the top of import statement which is `import react from 'React'`

```
Resolve error: unable to load resolver "node".eslintimport/namespace
Resolve error: unable to load resolver "node".eslintimport/no-extraneous-dependencies
Resolve error: unable to load resolver "node".eslintimport/default
Resolve error: unable to load resolver "node".eslintimport/no-duplicates
Resolve error: unable to load resolver "node".eslintimport/order
Resolve error: unable to load resolver "node".eslintimport/no-self-import
Resolve error: unable to load resolver "node".eslintimport/no-cycle
Resolve error: unable to load resolver "node".eslintimport/no-relative-packages
Resolve error: unable to load resolver "node".eslintimport/no-named-as-default
```

Before I migrate yarn berry, these errors have never been occurred.

However, when I added typescript object has `project: 'tsconfig.json'` inside of `import/resolver` like this:

```
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      typescript: { // here
        project: 'tsconfig.json', 
      },
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      },
    },
    'import/parsers': {
      '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },
```

The errors are gone.

I have solved the issue but I have question.

What does `typescript` option inside `import/resolver` do with yarn berry?

Answer (score 1):

The `import/resolver` is for letting ESLint understand the project's setup in regard to paths etc.

If I'm not mistaken, it is used by this dependency: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-typescript

Answer (score 0):

It's used by the `import` plugin (and more generally, `x/y` in ESLint config means `x` is the plugin name) and documented at https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file#resolvers:

> With the advent of module bundlers and the current state of modules and module syntax specs, it's not always obvious where `import x from 'module'` should look to find the file behind module.
>
> ...
>
> However, webpack allows a number of things in import module source strings that Node does not, such as loaders (`import 'file!./whatever'`) and a number of aliasing schemes, such as `externals`: mapping a module id to a global name at runtime (allowing some modules to be included more traditionally via script tags).
>
> In the interest of supporting both of these, v0.11 introduces resolvers.

`typescript` is another resolver, already linked in the other answer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-typescript

> This plugin adds TypeScript support to eslint-plugin-import (Or maybe you want to try eslint-plugin-i for faster speed)
>
> This means you can:
>
> - import/require files with extension .cts/.mts/.ts/.tsx/.d.cts/.d.mts/.d.ts
> - Use paths defined in tsconfig.json
> - Prefer resolving @types/* definitions over plain .js/.jsx
> - Multiple tsconfigs support just like normal
>   imports/exports fields support in package.json